# How do I write power series for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n)(n-1)(z/5)^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

What I know is that $n(n-1)$ is the derivative of $\frac{n^3}{3}-\frac{n^2}{2}$.I don't know what to do next?
I have even compared it with $\sum(a_n z')$
and found that here $a_n$ is my $n(n-1)$ 
and my $z'$ is my $z/5$.

What to do next??

Comment: I reformatted your question using MathJax. Please check if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $$P(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n$$
Differentiate twice to get $$P''(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
Multiply both sides by $x^2$ to get $$Q(x)=x^2P''(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}n(n-1)x^{n}$$
Lastly, substitute $x=z/5$ to get $$Q(z/5)=\sum_{n\ge 0}n(n-1)(z/5)^{n}$$
So, go back to the first step and take $P(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and follow through each succeeding step, taking derivatives twice, multiplying by $x$, and substituting.